# outer function in R

Tags: r

```
y <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),3,3)
p <- 3
oldgamma <- as.matrix(rep(1,3))
func1 <- function(i, j, y, oldgamma) {
  return(y[i,j]/(oldgamma[i] + oldgamma[j]))
}
func1 <- Vectorize(func1)
outer(1:p, 1:p, func1, y, oldgamma)
```

it returns the error message:
Error in y[i, j] : incorrect number of dimensions

Could anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you show the expected output

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
y/(oldgamma[row(y)]+oldgamma[col(y)])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  0.5  2.0  3.5
#[2,]  1.0  2.5  4.0
#[3,]  1.5  3.0  4.5
```

Or

```
 y/with(expand.grid(rep(list(1:p),2)),
              oldgamma[Var1]+oldgamma[Var2])
```

Or using your code

```
 func1 <- function(i, j, y, oldgamma) {
  return(y[cbind(i,j)]/(oldgamma[i] + oldgamma[j]))
 }
outer(1:p, 1:p, func1, y, oldgamma)
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  0.5  2.0  3.5
#[2,]  1.0  2.5  4.0
#[3,]  1.5  3.0  4.5
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Your answer really helps a lot. The first method you give me is amazing. By the way, for my code, I am not sure why using cbind() can fix the problem. Could you explain a little bit?

Comment: @meng `cbind` will provide the `row`, `column` index as a matrix, which will be the same as `outer(1:p, 1:p, function(i, j) y[matrix(c(i,j), ncol=2)])`.  But, I guess you don't even need `outer` to solve this.